# Change tracking with EF over time?

Tags: entity-framework

I'd like to know what is the best practice to track and/or persist changes over time if I use EF. I'd like to get started with EF for a new project. What I need is a kind of change history.

That's how I did it before: If a record was created it was saved with an ID and with the same ID as InvariantID. If the record was updated i marked it as deleted and created a new record with the new values and a new ID but the same InvariantID. Like this I always had my current record but a history of changes as well.

This works perfectly fine for my scenarios. The amount of historical records is not an issue because I use this usually only for data that's not changing very often.

Is this build in EF somehow or what's the best way to get this behavior for EF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not build into EF and it will not work this way. I even don't think that it is a good approach on the database level because it makes referential integrity very complex.

With EF this will work only if you use following approach:

- You will use conditional mapping for your entity - condition will be `IsDeleted = 0`. It will ensure that only non deleted entities will be used in queries.
- You will have mapped stored procedure for delete operation to correctly set `IsDeleted = 1` instead of really deleting the record
- You will have to manually call `DeleteObject` to delete your record and after that you will insert new record - the reason is that EF is not able to deal with scenario where entity change its PK value during update.
- Your entities will not be able to participate in relations unless you manually rebuild referential integrity with some other stored procedure
- You will need stored procedure to query historical (deleted) records

Comment: Oh dear. That sounds a bit complicated. But I can see your points. What would be a better aproach if I need a kind of a snapshot? Let's say I'll have a vehicle related to a booking. Now I always need the vehicle state as it was at the time the booking was saved even if the vehicle is updated in the database. My first thought might be to store the related information along with the booking as well. But not sure if this is the way to go. But with this approach I should be able to use EF as it should. Without the pain points you showed.

Comment: I always used separate table for historical data. Either one per table or one for all tables (that requires some data serialization). Inserts to these tables were either done directly from the application or from triggers. SQL Server 2008 also has its own built-in change tracking mechanism but I have never use it.